# SQL unnecessary FROM tables

Tags: sql, performance, select

I am making a query that only corresponds to one table, however, multiple tables are being searched through. Here is an example that is similar:

```
SELECT Earth.moon
FROM Earth, Mercury, Venus, Jupiter
```

There is no reason that the other planet's tables should be being searched through since we are looking for columns(Earth.moon) that could only be in the Earth table. However, the query becomes very slow when Mercury, Venus, and Jupiter are included.

Without simply removing Mercury, Venus, and Jupiter from the query since the column being searched for is dynamically populated, how can I avoid searching through unnecessary tables?

Comment: The query you shared is the same query you are running on the database?

Comment: What is your ACTUAL query and schema?

Comment: If you are dynamically populating the _column_ then you also need to dynamically populate the tables in the from clause. BTW, dynamic SQL is a bit of a code smell. Not knowing what a cross join is, is also a code smell.

Comment: Poor design. Have one common table, `planets`!

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Answer (score 1):

When you include all four tables your query becomes slow because you are producing an "Implicit Cross Join". See [Cross Join](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Cross_join) for details.

Just remove the unneeded tables to make your query faster. Besides, a cross join produces multiple repetitions of the same rows, one per each possible combination of rows on all tables -- aka the "Cartesian Product". That makes it really slow when you have a high number of rows per table.

Comment: Removing the unneeded tables is not an option since the query is based on a controller in the background where a user asks for a certain column. Is there someway to omit unnecessary tables from the resulting set by first checking if the column is inside it to begin with, or not checking some tables at all since anything that is "Earth".column won't be found in anything but the Earth table?

Answer (score 0):

The query must first join all `Earth` rows to all `Mercury` rows, and then to all `Venus` rows, and then to all `Jupiter` rows, to produce this cross joined table, called a [Cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product):

```
Earth.Moon  Mercury  Venus    Jupiter
==========  =======  =======  =========
Luna        No Moon  No Moon  Calysto
Luna        No Moon  No Moon  Ganymede
Luna        No Moon  No Moon  Io
etc.
```

Your query may only return one column, Earth.Moon, but the query must produce a separate row for each combination of rows in each of the 4 tables.  Therefore, you get a very boring list that repeats "Luna" for a number of rows equal to `(# Earth rows) X (# Mercury Rows) X (# Venus Rows) X (# Jupiter Rows)`:

```
Earth.Moon
==========
Luna
Luna
Luna
etc.
```

Comment: Since Mercury has no rows, the cross join result will be empty.

Comment: Yes, thank you.  I know that Mercury has no moons.  I am assuming these are replaced table names, and these tables probably actually have data, so I am playing along and assuming that other rows exist.  Perhaps "row1" and "row2" would be more helpful, but the OP did not specify the schema or content of these tables.